# appending くれる to verbs for unwanted things that someone else did

Tags: giving-and-receiving

Appending くれる to the て form of a (normal) verb means that someone else did the work. For example:

`食べてくれた` - (someone) ate it (and I am happy he ate it)

The sentence above has a nuance that the person who ate, did a favour to me, and that favour was that he ate the food (whatever the reason, he did me a favour).

The question is, what if I didn't want that someone to eat the food, but that someone still ate the food (and I am pissed about it). In this case, will it be possible to use the same sentence structure? I.e:

`食べてくれた` - (someone) ate it (and I am super pissed that he ate it)

If it is possible to use くれる even in the second example above, a second question arises and that is, how would I know if the action done was in favour of or was in spite of me. For example, if someone was to tell me `食べてくれたな`, how would I know if he is pissed that I ate it, or he is happy that I ate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what if I didn't want that someone to eat the food, but that someone still ate the food (and I am pissed about it).

How about 「食べ**やがった**(な)。」「食べ**やがって**！」, using 「やがる」?
You can also say 「**よくも**食べやがったな。」「**よくも**食べやがって！」 or just 「**よくも**食べたな！」
(But please note that 「～やがる」 and 「よくも」 both sound pretty strong, angry and rough.)

> will it be possible to use the same sentence structure?

Yes, you could say 「食べて**くれた**な。」 *sarcastically*.
You could also say 「**よくも**食べてくれたな。」, where よくも explicitly shows that you're pissed off.

> how would I know if the action done was in favour of or was in spite of me. For example, if someone was to tell me 食べてくれたな, how would I know if he is pissed that I ate it, or he is happy that I ate it?

I think you should just see from the tone of the voice and the speaker's facial expression.

[image]

Comment: Would the passive work? Something like 「食べてくれられた」 or just 「食べられた」; I was thinking about this option because as far as I know passive can also be used to show that an action was done and that displeases someone.

Comment: @Mauro 「食べてくれられた」 sounds unnatural. 「食べられた」 would work when you're talking about the 3rd person's action. This is **suffering passive/indirect passive** (迷惑の受身/間接受身), right? eg 「弟にプリンを食べられた！」(My brother ate my pudding (and I'm pissed off)!)

Comment: I've only ever heard やがった in anime (JoJo to be specific). I get the slightest feeling that using it in real life would make me seem like a very theatrical person or would give people the impression that I might have watch way too much shounen anime. Is やがって actually ever used in real life? I'd think the most used would probably be よくも食べたな！

Comment: Speaking of @Mauro answer, I'd think 食べられた、あんたに！ would also work, but i do agree that most of the time, it's used in 3rd person context